# Google Cloud NVIDIA Marketplace Solution fails right out of the box

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to deploy the nvidia-gpu-cloud-image, titled "NVIDIA GPU-Optimized Image for Deep Learning, ML & HPC." This is the "Marketplace Solution" provided by NVIDIA. I use all of the default settings for the deployment, with the A100 GPU.

When I ssh into the VM for the first time, it asks "Would you like to download the latest NVIDIA drivers so NGC can finish installing?" I select yes, but the installation fails. Any idea what's going on? Here's the full output:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-1032-gcp x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sat Jul 24 03:48:54 UTC 2021

  System load:  1.09               Processes:             213
  Usage of /:   19.1% of 30.84GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 0%                 IPv4 address for ens5: 10.240.0.37
  Swap usage:   0%


50 updates can be applied immediately.
30 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


The list of available updates is more than a week old.
To check for new updates run: sudo apt update


The following GCP CLI version has been pre-installed. Begin using the GCP CLI by first configuring your credentials using 'gcloud init'

name:    google-cloud-sdk
summary: Command-line interface for Google Cloud Platform products and
  services
publisher: Cloud SDK (google-cloud-sdk*)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/google-cloud-sdk
contact:   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/
license:   unset
description: |
  Command-line interface for Google Cloud Platform products and services
commands:
  - google-cloud-sdk.anthoscli
  - google-cloud-sdk.bq
  - google-cloud-sdk.docker-credential-gcloud
  - google-cloud-sdk.gcloud
  - google-cloud-sdk.gsutil
  - google-cloud-sdk.kubectl
snap-id:      MJbt3BgxESyOON7gqKVEnA06NLRM3Dxd
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04
refresh-date: today at 03:48 UTC
channels:
  latest/stable:    349.0.0 2021-07-20 (190) 243MB classic
  latest/candidate: ^                              
  latest/beta:      349.0.0 2021-07-20 (190) 243MB classic
  latest/edge:      349.0.0 2021-07-20 (190) 243MB classic
installed:          349.0.0            (190) 243MB classic


Welcome to the NVIDIA GPU Cloud image.  This image provides an optimized
environment for running the deep learning and HPC containers from the
NVIDIA GPU Cloud Container Registry.  Many NGC containers are freely
available.  However, some NGC containers require that you log in with
a valid NGC API key in order to access them.  This is indicated by a
"pull access denied for xyz ..." or "Get xyz: unauthorized: ..." error
message from the daemon.

Documentation on using this image and accessing the NVIDIA GPU Cloud
Container Registry can be found at
  http://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/index.html


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

NVIDIA GPU Cloud (NGC) is an optimized software environment that requires the
latest NVIDIA drivers to operate. If you do not download the NVIDIA drivers at
this time, your instance will shut down. Would you like to download the latest
NVIDIA drivers so NGC can finish installing? (Y/n)
Y
Enabling persistence mode...
nvidia-persistenced-init/README
nvidia-persistenced-init/install.sh
nvidia-persistenced-init/systemd/nvidia-persistenced.service.template
nvidia-persistenced-init/sysv/nvidia-persistenced.template
nvidia-persistenced-init/upstart/nvidia-persistenced.conf.template

Checking for common requirements...
  sed found in PATH?  Yes
  useradd found in PATH?  Yes
  userdel found in PATH?  Yes
  id found in PATH?  Yes
Common installation/uninstallation supported

Removing previous sample System V script... done.
Creating sample System V script... done.
Removing previous sample systemd service file... done.
Creating sample systemd service file... done.
Removing previous sample Upstart service file... done.
Creating sample Upstart service file... done.

Checking for systemd requirements...
  /usr/lib/systemd/system directory exists?  Yes
  systemctl found in PATH?  Yes
systemd installation/uninstallation supported

Installation parameters:
  User  : nvidia-persistenced
  Group : nvidia-persistenced
  systemd service installation path : /usr/lib/systemd/system

Adding user 'nvidia-persistenced' to group 'nvidia-persistenced'... done.
Installing sample systemd service nvidia-persistenced.service... done.
Enabling nvidia-persistenced.service... done.
Starting nvidia-persistenced.service... failed.

Aborting.
Cleaning up... done.
Skipping NV Peer Memory installation for non HPC SDK AMI
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: No I have not, do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the drivers as part of your startup script.

The installation  script is located at `/usr/bin/gcp-ngc-login.sh`.

Run `yes |  /usr/bin/gcp-ngc-login.sh true 1.2 2> /dev/null`  as part of your startup script.

The command comes from `/etc/skel/.profile`.